# What is the largest energy stored in a spring or other stress-based energy storage device that's ever been put in space?

Tags: energy, record, stage-separation

The question [What is the largest delta-v ever produced in space from mechanically stored energy?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28026/12102) asks of course about the delta-v produced, but here I'm asking about the largest amount of stored energy.

**update:** since there are a variety of ways to store energy, and since there are no answers, I'll narrow this down to springs and other mechanical devices which use mechanical stress/strain in solid materials.

Here's an example of a big spring pushing the first and second stages of an Antares rocket apart, from Scott Manley's video [The Antares Rocket - NASA's Less Famous Ride To The Space Station](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ttmG-HBUXE):

[image: The Antares Rocket - NASA's Less Famous Ride To The Space Station]  GIF

As another example there is a Falcon 9 "pusher"; a central rod from the first stage that extends through the nozzle of the 2nd stage engine and pushes on the back of the combustion chamber. For more see

- [Falcon 9 2nd stage pusher; how far does it continue to extend as it accelerates separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33754/12102)
- [Why is the Falcon 9 upper stage tumbling so much after separation? (SES-10)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21087/12102)

**Question:** What is the largest energy stored in a spring or other mechanical devices which use mechanical stress/strain that has ever been put in space? Ideally this should be *intentionally stored* mechanical energy.

"Put" implies that it didn't necessarily have to work or be used in practice.

Comment: It's going to be a flywheel

Comment: @Antzi I'd prefer an answer that mentions intentional storage of energy, I'll edit the question to reflect my preference. Thanks!

Comment: Might be a bolo despin system. It drains the spin energy of the entire spacecraft before being discarded into space.

Comment: @uhoh: One stores the unwanted energy in them to discard it. They are kinetic energy equivalent of heatsinks/radiators, or more accurately sublimators.

Comment: @SF. It's *discarded angular momentum*, not stored energy. I don't want to debate semantics with you, I'm clarifying my question. "In that sense they are *reaction masses* rather than mechanical energy storage devices. It's not like one ***stores*** **energy in them to be used later the way a mechanical spring, compressed on the ground, stores energy to be released later during the mission.**"

Comment: @uhoh: Angular momentum is inseparably bound with rotary kinetic energy. But it's energy stored only for discarding, not reuse, so I acknowledge this is not what you're asking about.

Comment: are pneumatics and hydraulics mechanical, in which case pressure fed tanks may be a candidate...